# how to generate the access token in kong manager api client credential based and how to use oauth2 for my endpoint through kong

Tags: kong, outsystems, kong-plugin

I have a service named test-service pointing to the host `https://personal-91siwo3k.outsystemscloud.com/` with path config of `APEXADIOrdering_API/rest/ADIOrdering/EndCustomersList`

Afterward, I created a route pointing to said service named test-endcustomer with host `ordering.com` path `/endcustomerslist`

After that, I enabled OAuth2 plugin in Kong manager GUI. I am able to get the provision key.

Then, I created a consumer named karthick and create OAuth2.0 credentials under the consumer tab, from there got client_id, client_secret. 
I also added a redirect_uri with the value of the endpoint that I want to use

With all the above configurations done, I made a HTTP request to Kong to request for an access token:

```
curl -X POST "https://localhost:8443/test-service/oauth2/token"?\
-d "grant_type=client_credentials" \
-d "client_id=PbgKKXnP1kqMiJwrXn8erCYwiJmt9DMg2" \
-d "client_secret=LRTI2CRTjpnppLBLYp3FoZVITLIoRs9b" \
--insecure
```

I can't get the access token with the error of:

```
{"message":"no Route matched with those values"}
```

I've configured Kong Admin API to `localhost:8001` and Kong Manager to `localhost:8002`, both are working fine and I'm able made HTTP requests to Kong without OAuth2.0 configured.\

Comment: Can you share the OAuth2.0 plugin configuration? where did you apply the plugin to? also, why are you requesting to `/test-service`? isn't the route you created has the path of `/endcustomerslist`?

Comment: http://localhost:8001/service/test-service/routes/test-route/plugins  name=oauth2
redirect uri=ordering.com/endcustomerslist

Comment: You have a space in the `client_id` parameter name.